# How to use grid or box layouts effectively? (Correctly?)

Tags: java, swing

How to use grid or box layout to correctly display information? (Ex. 5 students/rows, 3 grades/cols)

I have tried a grid layout, which worked well. However, it did not follow my rows/columns that I specified. I messed around with things such as using a box layout panel containing several grid layout panels. I've undone everything and now I'm back at square one. I now ask you for help.

```
Student: Test #1: Test #2: Test #3:
Name     100      50       75
Name     100      50       75
Name     100      50       75
Name     100      50       75
Name     100      50       75
etc...
```

^example of what I'm trying to achieve^

A bit more on what I said earlier, after about 2-3 rows/students, the layout changed and split the grades like such:

```
Student: Test #1: Test #2: Test #3:  Name     100   75   25
Name     100      50       75        Name     75    20   10
Name     50       75       100       Name     100   40   32
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Code:

```
public class GradesPanel extends JPanel
{


//Constructor
public GradesPanel()
{

    final int STUDENTS = 5;
    final int GRADES = 3;

    JTextField[] gradeField = new JTextField[GRADES];
    JPanel[] gradePanel = new JPanel[GRADES];
    JLabel[] gradeLabel = new JLabel[GRADES];
    JLabel[] header = new JLabel[GRADES + 1];
    JLabel[] nameLabel = new JLabel[STUDENTS];

    JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
    outerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    innerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(STUDENTS, GRADES));

    //Create headers

    header[0] = new JLabel("Student:");
    innerPanel.add(header[0]);
    for(int col = 1; col < (GRADES+1); col++)
    {   
        header[col] = new JLabel("Test #" + (col));
        innerPanel.add(header[col]);
    }


    //Create Label/TextField for each student/grade
    for(int row = 0; row < STUDENTS; row++)
    {
        nameLabel[row] = new JLabel("Name");
        innerPanel.add(nameLabel[row]);
        for(int col = 0; col < GRADES; col++)
        {   
            //gradeLabel[col] = new JLabel("");
            gradeField[col] = new JTextField(3);
            //innerPanel.add(gradeLabel[col]);
            innerPanel.add(gradeField[col]);
        }
    }

    //outerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
    //outerPanel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //add(outerPanel);
    add(innerPanel);
}   
}
```

Comment: Best answer: use a JTable to display tabular data -- the best tool for the job at hand. Otherwise you're stuck with using a JTextArea, making its Font Font.MONOSPACED, and using `String.format(...)` to format each row of data -- a sketchy solution at best.

Comment: As Hovercraft Full Of Eels hinted, that is not why you'd use Grid or Box Layout. Learn about Layout Managers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html). Basically, a Grid Layout is used when you want to place Java Components (panels, buttons, labels, etc) in container in a grid-like arrangement. Each grid area is a square and when the container changes in size, the components maintain their aspect ratio. Box layout is primarily used to stack components vertically (like stacking boxes); although it can be used to lay them horizontally (like Flow Layout).

Comment: BTW, I second the idea of using JTable.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be solved using layout managers which are used to help you organize components, not to display data. Your problem is how to display tabular data, not components, and two solutions immediately come to mind:

1. Use a JTextArea with a monospaced Font (`Font.MONOSPACED`), and format the rows of your data using `String.format("...",...)`, or even better:
2. Use a JTable to display the data. This component has been built *specifically* to display and manipulate tabular data. The tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).